# How to merge rows that have the same information in all columns except one?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a large data frame that looks smth like this:

```
A  1  2  3  4  ...
B  1  2  3  4  ...
C  1  2  3  4  ...
D  5  2  1  4  ...
E  3  2  3  9  ...
F  0  0  2  2  ...
G  0  0  2  2  ...
```

As you can see some rows are duplicate entries if you disregard the first column for a second. I would like to combine/merge these rows to generate something like this:

```
A;B;C  1  2  3  4  ...
D      5  2  1  4  ...
E      3  2  3  9  ...
F;G    0  0  2  2  ...
```

I could write a for loop, which iterates over the rows, but that would be neither pretty, nor efficient. I am pretty certain there's a better way to do this.

I thought I could:

1. slice the df so I have all columns except the first `slice <- df[, 2:ncols(df)]`
2. get a dataframe with all "duplicate" rows by `dups <- df[duplicated(slice)]`
3. get another dataframe with the "unique" rows by `uniq <- df[unique(slice)]`
4. merge them using all but the first column `merge(uniq, dups, by... )`

Except that won't work since unique doesn't return indices but a whole dataframe, which means I cannot index `df` with corresponding rows from `slice`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that A,B,C... are not rownames but actually part of the dataframe, entries given in string/character representation

Comment: Look at `aggregate` and related aggregation functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several functions that would do this. All of them are the common *aggregation* functions: `aggregate`, `tapply`, `by`, ..., and, of course, the popular "data.table" and "dplyr" set of functions.

Here's `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(V1 ~ ., mydf, toString)
#   V2 V3 V4 V5  V6      V1
# 1  0  0  2  2 ...    F, G
# 2  5  2  1  4 ...       D
# 3  1  2  3  4 ... A, B, C
# 4  3  2  3  9 ...       E
```

---

Other options (as indicated in the opening paragraph):

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, toString(V1), by = eval(setdiff(names(mydf), "V1"))]

library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  group_by(V2, V3, V4, V5, V6) %>%
  summarise(V1 = toString(V1))
```

Instead of `toString`, you can use the classic `paste(., collapse = ";")` approach which gives you more flexibility about the final output.

Comment: testing with aggregate skip a large portion of the data, not sure why.. Could NAs be an issue?

Comment: @posdef, Yes. `NA` would be an issue. If you read the help at `?aggregate`, you will see that the default action for the `na.action` argument in the formula method is `na.omit`.

Comment: the data.table solution did the trick, although I don't quite get how the `by=`  parameter works.

Comment: @posdef, that's just the columns that you want to group by. In this case, it's all the other columns other than the first. Instead of typing out all the names, I just used `setdiff`. Since it's everything except the first, you could also do `by = eval(names(mydf)[2:ncol(mydf)])`. `eval` is required in this case. Also, if this has answered your question, do consider *accepting* it.